# Apache Syntax Error

Tags: apache-2.2, centos

I have added:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

to my Apache configuration. It is now giving me a syntax error. The guide I am looking at told me to add it to the end of the file, which is what I did. I am running CentOS 6.5 and Apache 2.2.15.

The error message I am getting is:

```
Invalid command 'IncludeOptional', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

Could it be my Apache is outdated? Can somebody help me?

Comment: Your whole system is outdated. Try CentOS 7, and update it more frequently than once every two years.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thing is, my VPS provider only provides Centos 6.5, so far I have already managed to get 6.8 and I'm trying to install 7 currently.

Comment: You need a better VPS provider!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Apache 2.3.6 or later.

From [apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#includeoptional):

> #### IncludeOptional Directive
>
> Description:  Includes other configuration files from within the server
>   configuration files
>  Syntax:   IncludeOptional
>   file-path|directory-path|wildcard
>  Context:    server config, virtual
>   host, directory
>  Status:   Core
>  Module:    core
>   **Compatibility:  Available in 2.3.6 and later**